# is my proof for uniqueness of left and right inverses of a matrix correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $XM = MY = I$ for a nonsingular matrix $M$. Then prove that $X = Y$ .

$XM=MY=I$

$(XM)Y=Y(MY)=YI=Y$

$X(MY)=Y(MY)$

$X=Y$

Is this correct?

Suppose that $XM =YM =I$ for a matrix $M$. Then $Y =X$.

$YM= XM=I$

$(YM)X=(XM)X=XI=X$

$Y(MX)=X(MX)$

$Y=X$

From this, the left and right inverses of a nonsingular matrix are
the same unique matrix.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your working. Perhaps it would help to put reasons, written in words, between the steps? For example, you could say $XM = MY = I$ **by assumption**, then something like $X^2M = XMY = XI$ **multiplying on the left by $X$**, etc? Certainly for the first part, looking at $XMY$ as both $(XM)Y$ and $X(MY)$ is a solid place to start. For the second, you might find that it's not true for all $M$ (unless you're still assuming $M$ is non-singular?).

Comment: A great way to improve your work is to write fewer formulas and more words. A sequence of isolated formulas is really difficult to understand, because their logical connection must be guessed by the reader.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to do the following:
$$ Y=IY=(XM)Y=X(MY)=XI=X $$